# How to retain formatting on new line TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, vb.net, winforms, tinymce

Using TinyMCE v4, whenever formatting is set i.e bold/colour, the style is lost if you use the return key to get to a new line. I've searched the documentation but have been unable to find any settings which cause this, it is worth noting that the demo on Tiny MCE's site retains formatting across lines.

Does anybody know the option responsible for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely culprit is the `keep_styles` settting:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#keep_styles